# Skipping the print statemnt ! Why?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10,0.6)
allNodeCuts = nx.all_node_cuts(G1)
a = list(allNodeCuts)

for i in allNodeCuts:
    print(i)
```

In this version of the code, `print(i)` does not occur. However, if I move the code `a = list(allNodeCuts)` after the for loop, the loop runs and elements are printed. Why does this happen?

Comment: how about this ?  `for i in list(allNodeCuts):    print(i)`

Comment: `allNodeCuts` is likely a generator - you can get its contents once, but once it is exhausted, you can't get values from it again. Try `for i in a:`

Comment: This question would be a fantastic candidate on why debugging is essential in any programming language. 1 breakpoint and you'd have probably figured out that either that list is empty or (in your case) not a list at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I [edit]ed the post to fix the code formatting. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to understand how to format code properly.

Comment: @JustLudo that would still leave the conceptual question about how generators work. So it would be more clearly a duplicate question, but still a question that needed to be asked. (Also, it was surprisingly difficult for me to find a good duplicate target.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Without going to much offtopic: I agree with that, but it would def. help finding out that what you expect to be a list actually isn't. You don't need knowledge per se on what a generator is.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `allNodeCuts` is a [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) and if you list all its elements, you "consume" it (i.e. the pointer is set to the end).

You can see this behavior in the following example:

```
sq = (x**2 for x in range(3))
type(sq)
# generator
for i in sq:
    print(i)
# 0
# 1
# 4
```

If you run the loop again the generator is empty:

```
for i in sq:
    print(i)
```

To be able to iterate through a generator without losing it one can  create a copy with `itertools.tee`

```
from itertools import tee

sq, sq_copy = tee(x**2 for x in range(3))
list(sq)
# [0, 1, 4]

# now generator is empty because exhausted
list(sq)
# [] 

# copy is not consumed
list(sq_copy)
# [0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Convert the generator to a list, and iterate over the list

```
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(10,0.6)
allNodeCuts = nx.all_node_cuts(G1)
a = list(allNodeCuts)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should loop a that is:

```
for i in a:
    print(a)
```